# Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am just created simple .NET core webapi project using https://github.com/omnisharp/generator-aspnet

Then trying to run the app on Ubuntu Subsystem.

When I am running `dotnet start` I am getting an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.Check(Int32 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.GetSockIPEndPoint()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListenerPrimary.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<>c.<StartAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.ListenerPrimary.<StartAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at WebApp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

However when I am running the app just on windows using same command in `cmd` all working just fine.

Any thoughts how to fix that?
WebApi using port 5000 as default.

**UPDATE:**

I just specify the default port inline using `.UseUrls("http://*:5000")`

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
                .Build();
```

So now it is just working fine. However I haven't change the port value.
**Any thoughts why port `5000` not working in Ubuntu when it was not specified?**

Comment: Which port are you using? And does another application on your Linux use that port?

Comment: @Tseng, just updated my question.

Comment: http://*:5000 allows to use any IP4 and IP6 addresses from any interface, so although it still uses 5000 port, the another address may be used

Comment: Ah yes. I had a similar issue once, but I thought it was fixed already. I had it on Azure App Service though, as it was trying to bind to IPv4 and IPv6. Did you tried to bind to `http://0.0.0.0:5000` rather than to `http://*:5000`? The GitHub Issue https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/766 and the related issue https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/231

Comment: Last but not least, you can follow the last comment: tand try putting `UseIISIntegration()` after `UseUrls`, like this `UseUrls("http://*:5000").UseIISIntegration()` and unless you plan to ever host it on IIS, you can also remove it completely