# Error With Asp.NET Core on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core

I'm trying to follow the steps here to get an ASP.net core running on Ubuntu

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started.html

I followed the steps to install .NET core and verified that is running ok.

The ASP app builds without errors, but when I try to run the ASP app, 'dotnet run' the following exception is thrown:

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.Check(Int32 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.GetSockIPEndPoint()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListenerPrimary.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<>c.b__6_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.ListenerPrimary.d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at WebApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)

I've searched around the webz for an a solution, but couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: basically the error is:  Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use at

Comment: Windows is more stable than Linux? That's a pretty good joke.

Answer (score 0):

Some other program on your system is already using the port the ASP.NET web server is trying to bind to (another dev web server, perhaps). Use the command `sudo netstat -ltp` to find out what's listening and stop the servers that do, or alternatively, have the ASP.NET web server use another port, using one of the techniques described [in the relevant issue on the ASP.NET github](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639), e.g. by invoking `dotnet run --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:1234`.

Comment: Nothing else is listening on that port. Also tried dotnet run with the server URL params, which didn't work. The only that worked for me was to add .UseUrls("http://*:5000") to Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had to add the .UseUrls("http://*:5000") setting to the Program.c s file.

[Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169382/error-98-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error occurs due to closed the web site and terminated hosting irregularly (missed 'ctrl+c', instead probably with 'ctrl+z'); However, the tcp:{port} still be listening, you've to terminate or kill the process manually by '*kill -9 pid*'